# Lost sound of video after export

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am facing very weird issue of sound lost.

I am working on adding text on video

The problem is when i am entered into my video screen, initially the video in on mute mode and when i add text and make a video the new video which has text layer is added comes with no sound :(

I have tried solution also but not works

When the video is unmute and if i am adding text at that time everything works but with mute sound lost happens

I also tried when user tap on save i unmute the player's sound and do pause of video and display indicator to show that video is in processing but still it export video without sound

It only works when the player sound initially unmuted.

The problem is i don't want that initially the video is in mute way and when the text video is in processing suddenly the video play with sound.

Here the code i am using

```
- (void)videoOutput : (NSURL *)videoURL : (CGRect )frame : 
 (UITextView *)videoCaption :(UIImage *)image
 {
     AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoURL 
     options:nil];

    // 4 - Get path
     NSArray *paths1 = 
     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs1 =  [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo.mp4"]];
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs1];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs1])
{
    @try
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:myPathDocs1 error:nil];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERRRRORRRRRRR %@",@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
    @finally
    {
    }
}

// 1 - Early exit if there's no video file selected
if (!videoAsset) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Load a Video Asset First"
                                                   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}

// 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];


// 3 - Video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration)
                    ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);

// 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:videoAsset.duration];

// 3.3 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

float renderWidth, renderHeight;
renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

[self applyVideoEffectsToComposition:mainCompositionInst size:naturalSize :frame :videoCaption];

// 4 - Get path
  NSArray *paths = 
  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-
  %d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

// 5 - Create exporter
    AVAssetExportSession *exporter1 = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] 
    initWithAsset:mixComposition
    presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    exporter1.outputURL=url;
    exporter1.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exporter1.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    exporter1.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
     [exporter1 exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self exportDidFinish1:exporter1];
        });
    }];
```

}

---this is method for add text ------------------------

```
-(void)addText:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:
(CGSize)size :(UITextView *)videoCaption : (CGRect)textviewFrame
{

// 1 - Set up the text layer
CGFloat height = textviewFrame.size.height;


CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"AvenirNext-Medium"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:videoCaption.font.pointSize];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, size.width , height)];
subtitle1Text.wrapped = YES;
[subtitle1Text setString:videoCaption.text];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

// 2 - The usual overlay
CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];


overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10 , size.height/2 - (height/2),size.width-20  , height );
[overlayLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor ]];
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[parentLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor ]];
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[videoLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor]CGColor ]];

[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                             videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

}

If any one has same issue then please help me to resolved it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you show the relevant parts of your code you probably won’t get much help.

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far.

Comment: Hi guys

I have updated code please let me know if you can help me.